# Is there a way to perform Call in Windows Phone 7 without pressing any buttons?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to perform Call in Windows Phone 7 without pressing any buttons?(If I use the PhoneCallTask then I will have to press the call button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Actions like this deliberately require user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, no. In my personal opinion, it's unlikely to come in the near future either because of the potential for abuse - letting apps call premium rate numbers without any user confirmation would be a bit of a minefield.